# Why onload="function" works and jquery.load doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm loading a SVG file to a `<object>`, and one of my problems now, is to figure out why the atribute inside the `<object onload="function" />` works, but `obj.load(function(){});` doesen't

Are they different? load can only be performed in Images, and in the body?

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is a part of the code:

```
var cont = $('<div class="file" >'+file.file_name+'</div>'); 

        var render = $('<object id="file_'+file.id+'" data="/while1/pcbsfiles/view/'+file.id+'" type="image/svg+xml"/></object>');
        cont.append(render);
        render.css('visibility', 'hidden');

        cont.load(function(){
            //
            render.removeClass('position');
            render.removeClass('left');
            alert("aaaaaa");
            render.fadeIn();
        });
```

I tried with `cont.load`, `render.load`, `$('#file_'+file.id).load` also

Comment: Is the obj in obj.load a jQuery object?

Comment: As @mplungjan asks, or how about `obj.onload = function(){...};`?

Comment: i tried with obj.onload, but didn't worked also... can it be a jquery object?

Comment: worked with the doom object: `render.get(0).onload = function(){};`, but why does not work with jquery? @mplungjan

Comment: Not sure. Try render.on("load",function()... In images the load event handler has to be set before the source is set, perhaps jQuery is too late

Comment: AFAIK load events don't bubble, so you should definitely go with `render.load()`

Comment: It still not working... so i made with the `onload="callFunction(id)"`... Yes, the obj in obj.load is an jQuery object =] @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

I believe the .load declaration needs to be directly after you create the object, before you append it to another object. I can't give specifics as to why, but I've had a similar problem before.

Try something more like this:

```
var cont = $('<div class="file">'+file.file_name+'</div>');
$(cont).load(function(){
    var $render = $(render);
    $render.removeClass('position');
    $render.removeClass('left');
    alert("aaaaaa");
    $render.fadeIn();
});

var render = $('<object></object>');
$(render).attr('id', 'file_'+file.id)
    .attr('data', '/wihlte1/pcbsfiles/view/'+fild.id)
    .attr('type', 'image/svg+xml')
    .css('display', 'none');
$(cont).append(render);
```